# Сontour integral

Tags: integral-equations

everyone. Can you help with the task? [image]

Comment: Don't you just write down the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica is great at checking contour integration results, even very complicated ones.  If you're taking Complex Analysis, it's a good idea to learn how to check your work.  This is an easy one because by the Residue Theorem, it's zero.  But suppose it was a very complicated one and I solved it analytically and found it to be zero.  How could I check my work?  I would numerically integrate it as follows:

```
myz[t_] := 1 + 1/2 Exp[I t];
myf[z_] := 1/(z^2 (z^2 + 4));
NIntegrate[myf[z] D[myz[t], t] /. z -> myz[t], {t, 0, 
 2 \[Pi]}]

2.17925*10^-17 - 3.14419*10^-17 I
```